# Cross-thread operation not valid in Label Array

Tags: vb.net, arrays, visual-studio-2010, label

I have a problem: When  try to change the text of a label array (label(1).text = "Lol") then I get a error:

```
"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'lblCSCH1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."
```

The code is this:

```
    Private Sub Cliente_Receive(ByRef message As String) Handles Cliente.Receive
    Dim anterior As String
    Dim corte As Integer
    Dim canal As String
    Dim lblCSCH() As Label = {lblCSCH0, lblCSCH1, lblCSCH2, lblCSCH3, lblCSCH4, lblCSCH5, lblCSCH6, lblCSCH7, lblCSCH8, lblCSCH9, lblCSCH10}

    If Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(message, 3) = "<ch" Then
        corte = InStr(message, ">")
        If corte > 0 Then
            corte = corte - 1
            canal = Replace(LTrim(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left(message, corte), "h", ""), "c", ""), "<", ""), "0", " ")), " ", "0")
            'After this i Get just a number, for example 1 or 2
            lblCSCH(canal).Text = canal
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Cliente_Receive` event is occurring on a background thread.  You need to use `Control.Invoke` to marshal the call back to the UI thread.

The only change you need to do is to change this:

```
'After this i Get just a number, for example 1 or 2
lblCSCH(canal).Text = canal
```

To:

```
'After this i Get just a number, for example 1 or 2
lblCHCH(canal).Invoke(Sub() lblCSCH(canal).Text = canal)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the form load section of your code.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
'Rest of load form data
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not the best way to go about this.  Better to handle the call correctly.